# Python scatter plot for large data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have a data set from a surface measurement. More precisely, I have an array that contains several million 3d points that form a surface when plotted. So far, I plotted this with the matplotlib scatter function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,s=0.5,c=z,cmap='hot',marker='+')
```

However, this a terribly slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this? The problem is that I cannot just sample the huge data set, that is, just drop, say, three of four points, since then the surface quickly gets transparent.

I guess I'm asking too much, but is there a way to even get an interactive 3d plot of such a data set?

Comment: you could try plt.plot(x,y, 'k.', markersize=0.1), or a different markersize. This is much faster, however, you can not use different colour for each point as with scatter. What is your data exactly?